# jOOQ code generation for multiple databases with different schemas

Tags: java, maven, jooq

For my project I want to use jOOQ, but I have 3 databases. Two of them are similar (staging, production) and the third is the database for the application, with a completely different schema.The database Version is the same for all of them, MySQl 5.6. The difference is between the used tables, in one database i got the company translations and in the other database some customers etc.. 
Plain SQL is very unreadable, because the queries are very complicated. 
I know this makes no sense, but this is what I got.

Is there a possible way to do the code generation for different databases with different schemas?

I use Maven for the code generation.

Comment: *"I know this makes no sense, but this is what i got."* - rest assured, this is what most people do :) What are you using for code generation? Maven?

Comment: Exactly. Sry forgot to say that.

Comment: In what way do the schemas differ?

Comment: Just completely other tables and one table got more datatypes etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you go about multiple executions of the jOOQ code generator plugin with Maven is the same as with any Maven plugin. By specifying multiple executions:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>exec-1</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>...</configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>exec-2</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>...</configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The individual executions are completely independent, and they each have their own configurations.

Comment: Thank you, i am not so familiar with Maven, but this is exactly what i need!

Comment: @M.Soldin: Learning by doing!

Comment: This is not working when moving the <configuration> part inside the <execution> tag, how this is working your side ?

Comment: @sahlouls It depends on how you execute Maven. There are some known limitations, which manifest specifically when invoking executions from IntelliJ. Unrelated to jOOQ: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27804862/521799, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2192660/521799, etc...

Comment: @LukasEder thanks for pointing that, the issue was related to IntelliJ and not maven itself.
I managed to create dedicated IntelliJ lauchers :

jooq-codegen:generate@generate-exec-1 -f pom.xml
jooq-codegen:generate@generate-exec-2 -f pom.xml